# can we install Flash player into iPhone?

Tags: iphone, flash, installation

I bought iPhone yesterday.
But, I noticed that I cannot watch Flash by iPhone.

So, I came up with the idea that we can install Flash player into iPhone.

please tell me whether we can do so or not.

And please tell me how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to flash is installing a browser like skyfire, or cloud browse, or Puffin browser.  I personally prefer puffin browser on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

To install flash on an iphone you would have to have an unlocked phone. Then you would have to use a Cydia tweak to get it going! Good luck

Comment: You do not need an unlocked phone.....